# How to create a string list from the loop in bash?

Tags: bash, list, for-loop

I have a following loop:

```
for chr in {1..3};
do
futureList="${variable1} ${variable2}"
done
```

I would like to modify it so that *futureList* appends new set of variables in each consecutive cycle. Expected outcome should look something like this:

```
echo $futureList

string1 string2, string3 string4, string5 string6 etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is good usecase to use arrays:

```
var1='string1'
var2='string2'

futureList=() # declare an array

for i in {1..5}; do
   futureList+=("$var1 $var2") # inside loop append value to array
done

# check array content
# decclare -p futureList
# or use printf
printf '%s\n' "${futureList[@]}"
```

```
string1 string2
string1 string2
string1 string2
string1 string2
string1 string2
```

Comment: How does this match the desired output?

Comment: No, it's more the question asked to increment 'string[n]' and not just echo the strings 1...5 times

Comment: OP mentioned that `futureList appends new set of variables in each consecutive cycle` which obviously can be easily done inside the while loop to achieve whatever output.

Comment: Which isn't proper English when you compare his desired output

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it.

```
n=1
for chr in {1..3}; do
  array1+=("string$n") array2+=("string$((n+3))")
  ((n++))
done
```

Save the formatted output in the variable futurelist.

```
printf -v futurelist '%s %s, ' "${array1[@]}" "${array2[@]}"
```

Check the output

```
echo "$futurelist"
```

Output

```
string1 string2, string3 string4, string5 string6,
```

I'm pretty sure someone will come up with more ways to do better.